# How to Group By Year and Month in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I would like to measure the count of ID and ATTRIBUTE from the source table and present the data as shown in the "Desired Report" below. I am using MySQL.

**Source:**

```
ID  |  DATE        |  ATTRIBUTE
--------------------------------
1   |  2012-01-14  |   XYZ
2   |  2012-03-14  |   
3   |  2012-03-15  |   XYZ
4   |  2012-04-24  |   ABC
5   |  2012-04-10  |   
6   |  2012-05-11  |   ABC
```

**Desired Reports:**

> **Count of Attribute**

```
   YEAR | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL | AUG | SEP | OCT | NOV | DEC
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2010 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0 
   2011 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0 
   2012 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0
```

> **Count of ID**

```
   YEAR | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL | AUG | SEP | OCT | NOV | DEC
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2010 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0 
   2011 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0 
   2012 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0
```

> **Percentage Complete  ( Count of Attribute / Count of ID )**

```
   YEAR | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL | AUG | SEP | OCT | NOV | DEC
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2010 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0 
   2011 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0 
   2012 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0
```

Here's the code I have so far. Thanks! And Also keep in mind, I need to extract the Month from the date field in my data but not sure how. Thanks.

```
SELECT YEAR(document_filing_date),MONTH(document_filing_date),COUNT(aif_id)
FROM (a_aif_remaining)
GROUP BY YEAR(document_filing_date),MONTH(document_filing_date);
```

Suggested answer doesn't work!! Not sure why, here is the error I get:

```
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(document_filing_date) = 1 THEN aif_id END) AS Jan, CO' at line 1"

SELECT YEAR(document_filing_date,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(document_filing_date) = 1 THEN aif_id END) AS Jan,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(document_filing_date) = 2 THEN aif_id END) AS Feb,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(document_filing_date) = 3 THEN aif_id END) AS Mar,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(document_filing_date) = 4 THEN aif_id END) AS Apr,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(document_filing_date) = 5 THEN aif_id END) AS May,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(document_filing_date) = 6 THEN aif_id END) AS Jun,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(document_filing_date) = 7 THEN aif_id END) AS Jul,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(document_filing_date) = 8 THEN aif_id END) AS Aug,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(document_filing_date) = 9 THEN aif_id END) AS Sep,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(document_filing_date) = 10 THEN aif_id END) AS Oct,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(document_filing_date) = 11 THEN aif_id END) AS Nov,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(document_filing_date) = 12 THEN aif_id END) AS Dec,
FROM a_aif_remaining
GROUP BY YEAR(document_filing_date);
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I've updated the question a tad. You can see the extent of my efforts. I've got the columns as a number and not "MMM" format and it's not yet grouped by year also. I want a matrix.

Comment: @BenJones you forgot a `)` after Year, that's why the suggested answer doesn't work. My solution counts the presence of an attribute (it won't count rows if attribute is null), your accepted answer counts the presence of a specific attribute, it's not clear from your question what you are really after

Comment: Thansk. I am after 2 things: (1) Count of aif_id (total) and (2) Count of the presence of any value for the 'attribute' (i.e. not NULL)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This query will count all the rows, and will also count just the rows where `Attribute` is not null, grouping by year and month in rows:

```
SELECT
  Year(`date`),
  Month(`date`),
  Count(*) As Total_Rows,
  Count(`Attribute`) As Rows_With_Attribute
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Year(`date`), Month(`date`)
```

(this because Count(*) counts all the rows, Count(Attibute) counts all the rows where Attribute is not null)

If you need your table in PIVOT, you can use this to count only the rows where Attribute is not null:

```
SELECT
  Year(`date`),
  Count(case when month(`date`)=1 then `Attribute` end) As Jan,
  Count(case when month(`date`)=2 then `Attribute` end) As Feb,
  Count(case when month(`date`)=3 then `Attribute` end) As Mar,
  ...
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Year(`date`)
```

And this to count all the rows:

```
SELECT
  Year(`date`),
  Count(case when month(`date`)=1 then id end) As Jan,
  Count(case when month(`date`)=2 then id end) As Feb,
  Count(case when month(`date`)=3 then id end) As Mar,
  ...
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Year(`date`)
```

(or, instead of counting id, you can use `Sum(Month(`date`)=1)` like in kander's answer). Of course you can combine both queries into this:

```
SELECT
  Year(`date`),
  Count(case when month(`date`)=1 then id end) As Jan_Tot,
  Count(case when month(`date`)=1 then `Attribute` end) As Jan_Attr,
  Count(case when month(`date`)=2 then id end) As Feb_Tot,
  Count(case when month(`date`)=2 then `Attribute` end) As Feb_Attr,
  Count(case when month(`date`)=3 then id end) As Mar_Tot,
  Count(case when month(`date`)=3 then `Attribute` end) As Mar_Attr,
  ...
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Year(`date`)
```

Comment: This looks like a great answer but it's not working for me... hmm

Comment: @BenJones why it is not working? What do you get? I'm counting the presence of an Attribute, if Attribute is not null Count(Attribute) will count the row, otherwise it won't

Comment: I don't understand the statement "Count(case when month(`date`)=1 then `Attribute` end) As Jan," I am trying to measure the count of recrods so count(id). Thanks

Comment: Case will return attribute if month=1, otherwise it will return null, and null values won't be counted, if you need to count all rows substitute attribute with id

Comment: curious why use `case` instead of `if` here?

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with the following, but have a feeling that there might be a more efficient way to go about this...

```
select
year(`date`) as 'YEAR',
sum(month(`date`) = 1) as 'JAN',
sum(month(`date`) = 2) as 'FEB',
sum(month(`date`) = 3) as 'MAR',
    -- Repeat until december
FROM `source`
WHERE `ATTRIBUTE` = 'XYZ'
GROUP BY 1;
```